# Nautilus, need to connect NFS share with username and password

Tags: nautilus, nfs, sharing

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS client.

In Nautilus I've managed to mount a file share on a Synology server (supports NFS 4.1 and earlier) without issue clicking on "other locations", connect to server and entering in nfs://[SERVER-IP-ADDRESS]/volume1/video. This creates a directory in /run/user/1000/gvfs$ automatically until I unmount. All fine, as I've set the directory share permissions on server side for "everyone" for now so it works.

However this isn't an ideal situation, I need to set it up for authenticated users only, I've got no issue doing this server side.

When I do set the server side share for authenticated users only, I can successfully mount under Nautilus, however I can't see/browse any files or directories. So I am assuming I need to mount with a username and password somehow. How can I do this? (so I can have it persistent and bookmarked under Nautilus).

(BTW I'm using Samba successfully, I want to do this with NFS now)

Many Thanks...